# Local notification is not being fired on next day

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, localnotification, ionic-native

I'm using [**Local Notifications**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/) plugin.I need to trigger the notification at 10.01 AM every day. I have used below code. It is working fine when I tested on the same day at a different time.Let's say `16H 5Min`. But it is not working automatically for the next day. I can guarantee that all the data are there for the next data. But it seems I have done something wrong here. Please tell me where is the error?

`Note:` Even on the same day this is not working if we put the app in background mode for around `1+ hours` or so.

**Note:** In debug mode where it is working fine. I don't know where is the problem. Any clue?

*app.component.ts*

```
constructor(){
 this.initializeApp();
}

  initializeApp() {
        try {
          this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            timer(60000, 60000).subscribe(val => {
             const hours = moment().format("H");
             const minutes = moment().format("m");
          if (hours == '10' && minutes == '1')              
                this.scheduleNotification();
                });
             });
        }
        catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }

 scheduleNotification() {
    let firstNotificationTime = new Date();
    firstNotificationTime.setDate(firstNotificationTime.getDate());
    firstNotificationTime.setHours(10);
    firstNotificationTime.setMinutes(1);
    firstNotificationTime.setSeconds(0);
    forEach(this.authenticationProvider.member.projects, (project: Project) => {
      forEach(project.transactions, (transaction: Transaction) => {
        if (transaction.dueOn != null && moment(transaction.dueOn).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
          const id = random(1, 1000);
          this.localNotifications.schedule({
            id: id,
            title: 'Due Today',
            text: `Payment for ${transaction.category.name}: ${transaction.description} of ${Number(transaction.totalPrice).toLocaleString()} is due today.`,
            data: { transaction: transaction, project: project },
            at: firstNotificationTime,
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from the way your code is written that `firstNotificationTime` will always be whatever today's date is when this line of the code runs:

```
let firstNotificationTime = new Date();
```

In the next few lines you change the hour, minute, and second, but you never change the date. You'll have to bump the date to the next day to get the notification on the next day.

Apart from that, you can get rid of this line:

```
firstNotificationTime.setDate(firstNotificationTime.getDate());
```

That does nothing other than set the date to itself.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. I have triggered this every min `timer(60000, 60000).subscribe(val => {` So on any day that will be happened. Could you tell me where's the error and how to fix that?

Comment: Here I have triggered the notification if it is `10.01 AM` `if (hours == '10' && minutes == '1')              
                this.scheduleNotification();
                });
             });`